# HD текстуры в OpenGL 2 Android

Tags: android, opengl

Стоит задача вывода с помощью `OpenGLES2` в `Android` `HD` текстуры(`1280х720px`).
Были рассмотрены следующие варианты:

-Вывод в `два треугольника`;

-Вывод в `прямоугольник`.

Реализовать все еще не получилось, несмотря на десятки прочитанных статей и опробованных примеров. Так же есть мнение что вывести `HD` текстуру нереально, ведь она `не степень двойки`. Совсем не важно как она будет выведена на экран в плане фигуры и т.д., просто нужен аналог вывода в `ImageView`.

Детали.
Результат должен быть аналогичен, как если бы мы выводили изображение с помощью `ImageView`, который `match_parent`. Вывод рассчитан строго на девайсы с дисплеем `HD`. Так же есть привязка к тому, чтобы текстура загружалась из основного класса, а не в классе `рендерера`. Так же добавлю, что для всего этого используем `GLSurfaceView`, который встроен в `RelativeLayout`, для обеспечения последующего отображения элементов `XML`.
Привожу урезанные части классов, чтобы не засорять кодом проекта описание.

`Class episodes` (в нем бы хотелось передавать текстуру):

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.episode);
    mGLSurfaceView = new GLSurfaceView(this);
    final ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    final ConfigurationInfo configurationInfo = activityManager.getDeviceConfigurationInfo();
    final boolean supportEs2 = configurationInfo.reqGlEsVersion >= 0x20000;
    if (supportEs2) {
        mGLSurfaceView.setEGLContextClientVersion(2);
        mGLSurfaceView.setRenderer(new render());
      }
      else
      {
        return;
      }
      ViewGroup container = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.mglid);
      container.addView(mGLSurfaceView);
    }

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    mGLSurfaceView.onResume();
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    mGLSurfaceView.onPause();
}

public void onClickBack(View view) {
    //тут меняем текстуру на другую
}
```

Теперь привожу `XML` данного `Activity`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/mglid"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
</LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Класс рендерера приводить не буду, так как он полностью взят из [ссылка](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/opengles/intro.php), идет после строки `В коде идёт обращение к классу LessonOneRenderer.` Код довольно сложен для понимания новичка, и я только смог убрать один из треугольников и убрать вращение.

Так как понятия не имею как лучше вывести изображения `HD`, буду рад любым советам, а может и частям кода, ведь код проекта я выложил (частично).

Заранее вам спасибо и прошу, не давайте мне ссылок на разные статьи, в том числе из `Хабра`, так как я уже десятки раз их читал, поэтому обратился сюда.
Я уверен что если мы вместе решим эту проблему, то это много кому поможет в будущем! Спасибо!

Comment: Примечание: сама реализация данного рендерера (безтекстурные вращающиеся треугольники) работает, отлично сочетается с элементами интерфейса XML.

Comment: нарисуй для начала текстурированный кубик,  ну как-то совсем не хочется мне тратить часа 3-4 чтобы написать то что тебе нужно. В друх словах то никак тут не объяснишь.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем ладно, я сегодня добрый, убил 3 часа и написал вам, то что вы хотели.

https://github.com/Karavanych/glesImages

по `onTouch` в любом месте , меняется изображение.
Тестировал на эмуляторе 4.4
Перед стартом есть небольшая задержка загружаются в текстуры 7 картинок 1280x854
гарантировать работу таких текстур на всех устройствах нельзя, ибо стандарт GLES 2.0 гарантирует только текстуры 1024x1024 насколько я помню. (GLES 3.0 т.е. все устройства с Android 4.4 и выше уже поддерживают текстуры минимум 2048x2048, это зафиксировано стандартом)

Поскольку брал классы из рабочих проектов, часть методов могут быть лишними, не удивляйтесь.

Еще неплохо бы в этот проект добавить сжатие текстур в форматы поддерживаемые openGL - это уменьшит время загрузки. Будет желание попробуйте.

Comment: Возможно, это хорошее решение, но плохой ответ - сделать работу за автора, описать поведение реализации, и не объяснить что и почему надо было сделать.

Comment: Ты издеваешься чтоли ? :)))) Ты же знаешь сколько там объяснять, если человек ни разу не работал с opengl :)

Comment: Было бы хорошо добавить параграф в начале, описывающий в общих словах *что* и *как* можно/нужно сделать ;-)